# Необходимо ли перед выходом из блока в цикле произвести delete, или вектор сделает это сам?

Tags: stl, c++

Имеется следующий блок кода на С++:

```
{
    vector<int*>v(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int *ptr = new int[10];
        v.push_back(ptr);
    }
    //... использую вектор
}
```

Ясно, что в цикле for утечки памяти не происходит. Вопрос: необходимо ли перед выходом из данного блока в цикле же произвести delete [] v[i], или вектор сделает это сам?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно чистить, сам вектор не будет этого делать. Если вам нужно, что-бы массивы удалялись после выхода из блока -- почитайте про умные указатели.

P.S. Правда использовать с auto_ptr вектор нельзя, придется либо писать свой вариант, либо использовать boost.

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит особо печься по таким мелочам, имхо! C++ и так имеет способность "стрелять в ногу"( я ничего против плюсов не имею, сам я ярый фанат этого языка ), а тут еще и о такой ерунде беспокоиться! Да, объекты контейнерных классов не имеют способности самоудаляться, но если уж это вам ТАК необходимо, то можно удалить объект в любой части программы, если он был определен глобально:

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       vector<*in >v(4);   // так произойдет утечка...не будет возможности удалить  
                              элемент после выхода из цикла.
       int *ptr = new int[10];
        v.push_back(ptr);
    }
    //... использую вектор
}
```

Comment: - В любой части программы удалять что-то - это в корне неверный подход (как противоречащий [`RAII`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)). Да и головной боли в случае `exception'ов` в таком варианте не избежать.

- Если объект определен **глобально** (пусть и в некотором ограниченном скоупе), то за его освобождение должен отвечать либо он сам, либо, в крайнем случае, самый внешний скоуп его использования. В противном случае размазывается область ответственности за него и совершенно неясно, кто и когда *вправе его освободить.*

Comment: - Если объект определен **глобально** (пусть и в некотором ограниченном скоупе), то за его освобождение должен отвечать либо он сам, либо, в крайнем случае, самый внешний скоуп его использования. В противном случае размазывается область ответственности за него и совершенно неясно, кто и когда *вправе его освободить.*

> Собственно, `std::shared_ptr` и `std::scoped_ptr` являются удачным воплощением описанных принципов на практике.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, благодарю за комменты! Из них можно подчерпнуть нечто ценное. Спасибо =)

Comment: Ты считаешь, что утечка памяти - это ерунда? Или я что-то не понял?